# How to say 'protect x from y'?

Tags: mandarin

In my routine HSK vocab study, I recently came upon the word 保护； to protect. Obviously, it works easily like any other verb in statements simply of protection, but I have no idea how to translate the concept of protecting one party from another. For example, "Our house protects us from cold weather", etc
Is there an other word to be used for this purpose, or is there a grammatical construction that uses 保护 for this purpose? Thanks heaps for any help!

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why? This question doesn't fit any downvote criteria IMO.

Comment: Upvotes for you!

Comment: 保护……免受…… (in Chinese)

Answer (score 4):

look up nciku or iciba, in fact iciba 翻译 seems to give a correct translation 我们的房子保护我们免受寒冷的天气， indicating that instead of using a preposition （from） Chinese uses a verb 免受，for more examples just look up iciba， nciku，one more example sentence showing same construction 这样的法规可以保护消费者免受有害或者危险药品的威胁。

Talking about HSK，HSK dictionary （汉语水平考试词典）has following entry for 保护：［义１］（动）保卫护理，不使！！受到！！损害 。。。。 indicating use of 不受到 (similar 免受) to translate ＂from＂ in this context